# can we merge 2 dataframe with different length and same groups?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 2 data frame with same group

```
    df1:

             household        person        trip        
                 1               1            1             
                 1               1            2             
                 1               1            3  
                 1               2            1             
                 1               2            2             
                 2               1            1            
                 2               1            2             
                 2               2            1 
    df2:

             household        person        trip         overlap
                 1               1            3             2
                 2               2            1             1
```

now I want to merge overlap column from df2 to  df1 like this

```
                household        person        trip        overlap
                 1               1            1             NA
                 1               1            2             NA
                 1               1            3              2
                 1               2            1             NA
                 1               2            2             NA
                 2               1            1            NA
                 2               1            2             NA
                 2               2            1             1
```

notice group in df2 is a subset of df1

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please use more time in searching, it's a quite famous problem with data manipulation (it's a dupe). Start reading this `?merge()`, but the link provided by @kath it a great resource.

Comment: `merge(df1, df2, all.x = TRUE)`